# How would I be able to search a massive text file? (20+GB)

Tags: php, html, text

I'd like to be able to search a 20GB+ .txt file on Windows 7. I have ~20GB of free RAM for a program to run (less RAM than the size of the txt file,) and a software raid 0 between 2 laptop hard drives that yields me about 100MB/s R/W speeds. The end goal is to have a web interface where you could put in a search query and it would tell you what number into the text file the query was found. There is a webserver already running on this computer (WAMP). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest to use an Database for this Job, and parse the file line by line with php to save it into an table.

Comment: although the db is probably the best solution, you could also consider installing grep for windows: http://www.wingrep.com/download.htm ... i am unsure about the windows version, but gnugrep  on *nix systems reads files one  line at a time. as long as you don't have one line greater than your ram it will work.

Comment: Do any of these programs have the ability to be executed from a webapp? 

"The end goal is to have a web interface where you could put in a search query and it would tell you what number into the text file the query was found." 

I may also add, this is 1 continuous string of an irrational number. You cannot break it up at any point.

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to re-invent searching.  We have nice databases for this task these days.  Even if you must start with a source text file of this size, I would load it into a database for searching.  Once loaded and indexed, you have a very efficient rig.

Now, you didn't specify what you're searching for and how so it's hard to give specific advice.  What I can tell you is that I've had great luck with text searches in Solr.  It's built for tasks like these.

Comment: Its one continuous number that cannot be broken up.

Comment: @heilstalin Of course it can... from your description, this is definitely something you can break up into pieces.

Comment: Nope. Its a continous irrational number to the 100 billionth number. Searching a number that lies between 2 breaks wouldnt be found.

Comment: @heilstalin That doesn't stop you from breaking this into pieces.  Consider segmenting so you can do your searching in parallel.  In the event that the substring isn't found, then you can search around the segment boundaries.  Don't assume that the naive solution is the only solution... there are many ways to solve this problem.